# LINQ to XML: Getting child values of elements

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, anonymous-types

Well, this one is my XML file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <setup>
    <Test>10</Test>
    <Copy>
      <Descr>AA</Descr>
      <Descr>BB</Descr>
    </Copy>
  </setup>
</config>
```

and this one is my LINQ query :(

```
Dim query = From q In XElement.Load("\MyXml.xml").Elements("setup") _
            Where q.Element("Test").Value = "SomeValue" _
            Select New With {.Test = q.Element("Test").Value, _
                             .CopyDescr = q.Element("Copy/Descr").Value}
```

Unfortunately, this one, produces the following straight-forward error.

```
The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.
```

So my question is, how can i get the child values contained in the `<Description>` too, without getting the error? You see i would love to load the Values contained in the `CopyDescr` to a `List of(String)` for a later usage...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you are trying to use an XPath expression, but this has nothing to do with XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I just found it. The `Descendants` does the trick.

```
.CopyDescr = q.Descendants("Descr")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath:

```
q.XPathSelectElements("Copy/Descr")
```

However this will return a list of elements. Probable you will need to join them together somehow, so your code is going to be:

```
.CopyDescr = String.Join( "," ,
   from qq in q.XPathSelectElements("Copy/Descr") select qq.Value
);
```